# Fallback value when validation fails

Tags: joi

(how) is it possible in joi to specify a fallback value that is used when the value does not match a schema?

pseudocode:

```
Joi.string()
    .regex(/\d/)
    .fallback('0') // .fallback does not exist, but I wish it did
```

e.g. when the value does not match the regex, I want to replace it with the fallback

In the [API docs](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md), I found some promising stuff, but not usable for my case: e.g. `any.default()`, `string.replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is if you use `Joi.compile()`.

```
Joi.compile([
  Joi.string().regex(/\d/),
  Joi.empty(Joi.any()).default('0'),
])
```

Hope it helps!